# How to: convert namingAlias from Jboss5 to Wildfly10 syntax

Tags: jndi, wildfly-10

How do i convert the following jboss 5 configuration into Wildfly10 syntax.

```
   <mbean code="org.jboss.naming.NamingAlias"
    name="jboss.mq:service=NamingAlias,fromName=clearviewAdapter/QueueConnectionFactory">
    <attribute name="ToName">java:/ConnectionFactory</attribute>
            <attribute name="FromName">java:/obfustreamAdapter/QueueConnectionFactory</attribute>
    </mbean>
```

As far as i have heard the NamingAlias is not supported in Wildfly anymore. So what to do in this scenario

Answer (score 1):

Can't remember the exact details from JBoss5 ...
But the naming subsystem can be used to add aliases for JNDI.
You might add it to the naming subsystem of your configuration like this:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.4">
  <bindings>
    <lookup name="java:global/AliasAppTwo" lookup="ejb:jboss-ejb-multi-server-app-two/ejb//AppTwoBean!org.jboss.as.quickstarts.ejb.multi.server.app.AppTwo"/>
   </bindings>
   <remote-naming/>
 </subsystem>
```

The lookup must not be available at startup, it will be solved during runtime.